# HTML/CSS List with Links generates a small "_" right at the end of the Link Element

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, html-table

On my new Website in the area of the footer, I got the problem that there are small lines at the end of an LinkObjekt(find a picture at the end hope you can see it). So the processed Website footer looks like "Startseite          _Pakete              _ [...]". Annother point is that the first " _ " is a link with the same direction as "Startseite" (an the second " _ " refers to "Pakete") but the Space between "Startseite" and "_" is not used as a link.

Do you have any solutions how i can fix that Issue?
For Troubleshooting the used code is attached.

```css
.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background-color: #212121;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer ul li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
    color: #0091EA;
}

.footer ul li a{
    color: #BDBDBD;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.footer ul li a:hover{
    color: #0091EA;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <center>
       <div>
           <ul>
               <li><a href="index.php">Startseite</li>
               <li><a href="angebot.php">Pakete</li>
               <li><a href="uberuns.php">Über Uns</li>
               <li><a href="gallerie.php">Gallerie</li>
               <li><a href="termine.php">Termine</li>
               <li><a href="login.php">Login</li>
               <li><a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt/Impressum</li>
               <li><a href="disclaimer.php">disclaimer</li>
               <li><a href="#oben">Nach oben</li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </center>
</div>
```

[View on the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcfXJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing ending anchor tag

```
<li><a href="index.php">Startseite</li>
```

versus

```
<li><a href="index.php">Startseite</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sometimes your so focused that you don't see the main part of it :D

Comment: You also have another error. The center tag is deprecated. So use CSS instead. You probably could also get rid of the DIV wrapper. The UL can be its own block.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't closing any of the links, so any space between them is going to be a link as well.

```
<ul>
                 <li><a href="index.php">Startseite</a></li>
                 <li><a href="angebot.php">Pakete</a></li>
```

...and so on. You need to close the `a` tags.